# 60's/70's children/YA book involving magic circles, magicians with numerical ranks, and perhaps a train

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

As a child in the mid-to-late 70s I was read a novel by a beloved teacher in grade school. I have only the vaguest recollection now of story elements to identify it:

It's a fantasy book, but I seem to remember it was set in the "real world" (not a complete fantasy world) and that there may have been, at one point, a train journey that was important to the story and that the group of protagonists were travelling on it.

There are magic users (I *think* simply called "magicians").  One recurring and important element is that these magicians have very distinct grades/ranks/levels which, as I remember, were numbered.  My vague recollection was that 10th was the highest rank, and that the antagonist of the story was of this level.

The rank of a magician/magic-user determines over what distance magic can be projected, which is an important element when the antagonist creates a magical sending (a storm perhaps) from a great distance away to attack or thwart the protagonists.  They are protected from this sending/storm by the power of a good magician.  This magician, however, is of a lower rank which means he can only do magic within the range of a magic circle of a certain size.  He can nullify the antagonist's sending/storm only within this magic circle.  I believe the idea of a magic circle is used often, at least at one point in the story.  The higher the rank of magician, the larger the magic circle they can affect magic within.  Until, at the rank of the antagonist, they can affect at infinite range.

Comment: The magic users on a train reminds me of "Silver on the Tree" by Susan Cooper, but the other details don't really match up

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez, thinking of susan cooper, "the dark is rising" comes to mind, a lot of the plot elements match